# Highcharts don't show data after remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm new to highcharts and get stuck here, please see if you can help me.

I want to be able to dynamically add and remove data in highcharts. My code works at the start, but when i finish adding data and want to remove all of it and start again, something strange happens. My data don't show anymore, just the bottom headings.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yt5o7c6h/)

```
chart.series[0].remove(false);
```

Please try to add, remove and then add code again via the buttons on top. If i change the remove method of highcharts to false (it is true by default) it is working, but the chart is not auto resizing anymore so this is not a solution for me.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: have you checked console for errors?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'complete' of undefined
35highcharts.js:153 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: Thanks i see the errors now, but i can't understand from where they are  coming from :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in 3.0.9 version. Try out 4.0.4:

```
http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yt5o7c6h/2/